Simplest prime test algorithm possible: what's its complexity?
We got the brute force algorithm:

Input: natural number $n$.
Set $k_{i+1}=k_i+1$, $k_0=2$, $i=0$
If $\frac{n}{k_i}$ is an integer, return $'\mathrm{Composite}'$, else, set $i=i+1$.
If $k_i^2\leq n$ repeat previous step, else return $\mathrm{'Prime'}$.
Terminate

I'm not very well-versed in computational complexity, but I can infer that this algorithm must have linear complexity ($O(n)$). In fact, while i was trying out some new abstract prime test I just developed, I always thought: "this is extremely tedious... Hopefully, a computer could make this way faster". But, isn't the algorithm I described also computable by machines? How can this one not be the fastest algorithm, since its just a linearly-scalated complexity is it actually linear?

It has $O(\sqrt{n})$ complexity, since $k$ will not exceed $\sqrt{n}$ and the operations inside the loop are performed in constant time

But wouldn't this mean its the fastest algorithm we know about?

Note that $O(n)$ is linear in $n$, but it's exponential in the length of the input.

This is trial division (without presieve to determine the prime numbers) , so the complexity is $O(\sqrt{n})$

The fastest known algorithm for general numbers is the quadratic sieve and this is unimaginably more efficient than trial division.

@MDJ what do you mean? It becomes exponential when we take in account the number of digits?

Also "computable" does not mean "feasible in practice". It just means that there is an algorithm at all to solve the problem.

@peter i understand empirically that every algorithm is faster than trial division for large numbers... But the theory is what I don't get: isn't linear growth an optimal "feasibility measure"? If it is, how is TD anything but linear?

@Peter, aren't AKS-type tests faster? Primality testing is a different problem to factorisation, right? Anyway you are right that there are heaps of faster algorithms than this. Simón, when people talk about the complexity of primality testing or integer factorisation, this complexity is indeed in terms of the number of digits of the input. Trial division takes exponential time relative to this. It's like the difference between multiplying $a$ and $b$ by computing $a + a + a + \dotsb$ vs doing long multiplication.

@IzaakvanDongen In fact, it is much easier to test whether a number is prime (in pratice usually Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely is used , although it is not fully deterministic but much faster than AKS (AKS just shows that primality testing is in $P$) , another approach is using ellipctic curves. If $N-1$ or $N+1$ can be fully factored , we even have efficient primality proofs.

If $N$ is huge and not special enough , we are usually content with very reliable tests and speak of "probable primes" , probable here usually means "virtually sure".

OK, now I see what the comment means , the routine just checks whether $n$ is prime , however , it also determines a non-trivial factor. Repeatedly used , we could eventually fully factor $n$.

@Peter: the Number Field Sieve is asymptotically way more efficient than your Quadratic Sieve, and has been for decades. But this is irrelevant here, since they are both factorisation algorithms, not primality-deciding algorithms.

@TonyK The differences between number field sieve and quadratic sieve are not so significant , unless we can make use of the special structure of a number , for example if it is of the form $a^n+m$ with large $n$ and small $m$. Also, the above algorithm would (if we let it run upto $\sqrt{n}$) , actually not just test whether $n$ is prime, but factor it.

@Peter: You are 20 years out of date. But as I said, this is not relevant here.

@TonyK I know the refinements , but as you said this is not relevant here. So, it is also pointless to debate which quadratic sieve is better. Let us stop the discussion here.

@SimónFlavioIbañez Yes, the complexity for these kinds of problems is usually not measured in terms of the number $n$ itself, but in terms of how we can input the number $n$, which is a string of symbols of length $\log n$.
